# CURL error: GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

Tags: php, curl, infusionsoft

I have infusionsoft api lib running on my server. In the code, I have to find contacts in infusionsoft using their method dsFind. If I use 5 as the limit to fetch no of contacts, it is working fine but when I make it more than 10, it is throwing below error:

ERROR: 8 - CURL error: GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.

The same code is working fine on some other server.

Comment: Can you post your query, so that we can verify there's no issue with the way it's constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly likely it is caused by the client tries to verify the server cert. You can try something as specified here: http://www.arashmilani.com/post?id=21

I have done it with pycurl and it works. Check php manual for the proper syntax.